# How could I express the idea that one person is learning the habits of other person?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I want to express the idea that one person is becoming like another person. I was thinking to use *color*, as in "Mr. X is getting colored in Mr. Y."

Is this a common usage?

Comment: "Those who go with the lame learns how to limp."

Comment: Some of the answers you've already recieved are probably best, but your idea isn't far off. I don't think it's common usage, but if there were enough context, I think it would work, but use "colored by..." instead of "colored with..." Common usage has to start somewhere. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider [rub off (on/onto somebody)](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/rub+off+on#rub_1__43), which means:

> *(of personal qualities, behaviour, opinions, etc.)* to become part of a person's character as a result of that person spending time with somebody who has those qualities, etc

I might say "Mr. Y is rubbing off on Mr. X" to mean that Mr. X is becoming like Mr. Y in general. Or I might refer to a specific positive or negative trait: "Your good manners have rubbed off on me."

Answer (score 3):

"picking up their habits"

Example usage:

> I am picking up my sister's habit of listening to the Beatles.
>     My second child is picking up all the bad habits of my first child.
>     I'm picking up the habits of my roommate.

If you particularly want to use "colour," it would be something like this:

> Steve is really colouring the behaviour of his partner.

...but it is not an idiom like "picking up habits..." and I would not recommend using that.

Incidentally: there is a somewhat humorous idiom "Well colour me happy!" which you may be thinking of, but it is not really related to habits and habit forming.

Answer (score 3):

One word is "copy catting."

> Mr. Smith is copy-catting Mr. Jones.

Another term is "learning by osmosis" (seeping in):

> Mr. Smith is learning Mr. Jones' tricks by osmosis.

Answer (score 1):

**Carbon copy**.  Mr. X is transforming into a carbon copy of Mr. Y. 
'Carbon copy' is defined as a person or thing that closely resembles another. 
**Clone** is another alternate term.

Answer (score 0):

In psychological terms, it's called "convergence".  Look up "convergence theory".